# Why does the string change itself when passing as a QueryString?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, query-string, urlencode

I work on a project based on Windows Phone 7.5.

I have page 1 which pass a URL as a QueryString. the e.Value.ToString() is **http://xiciimgs.xici.net/d189532038.0/001_7384_%B8%B1%B1%BE_%B8%B1%B1%BE_s.jpg** , and this is the right string.

```
    private void myWB1_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        string passingURL = e.Value.ToString();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(passingURL)) 
        {
           App.goToPage("/PictureViewPage.xaml?pictureurl=" + passingURL);
        }
    }
```

And on Page 2, I try to get the URL via the code below,

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string strUrl = "";
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("pictureurl", out strUrl);
        strUrl = Uri.EscapeUriString(strUrl);
    }
```

After the TryGetValue, strUrl is "**http://xiciimgs.xici.net/d189532038.0/001_7384_¸±±¾_¸±±¾_s.jpg**" , 
after the Uri.EscapeUriString , the strUrl turns out to be "**http://xiciimgs.xici.net/d189532038.0/001_7384_%C2%B8%C2%B1%C2%B1%C2%BE_%C2%B8%C2%B1%C2%B1%C2%BE_s.jpg**"

A little bouns, the App.gotoPage did nothing but navigate:

```
    public static void goToPage(string targetUri)
    {
        var rootFrame = (App.Current as App).RootFrame;
        rootFrame.Navigate(new System.Uri(targetUri, System.UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

---

**My question is why does this happen and how to get the right url?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the problem, 
[Uri.EscapeUriString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) the passing value first to avoid format exceptions during the navigation.

```
private void myWB1_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    string passingURL = e.Value.ToString();
    passingURL = Uri.EscapeUriString(passingURL);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(passingURL)) 
    {
       App.goToPage("/PictureViewPage.xaml?pictureurl=" + passingURL);
    }
}
```